# RadioButton is hidden unless checked

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, uwp-xaml

I have a radiobutton like this

```
<RadioButton
     GroupName="A"
     IsChecked="{Binding IsExternalAllEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationConverter}}" Margin="0,0,0,12">
     <TextBlock
          FontWeight="Normal"
          Text="xx"
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          LineStackingStrategy="BaselineToBaseline"
          LineHeight="18"
          Margin="0,-1,0,0" />
```

However, I can only see the radiobutton when it is selected, and if I set the background to some color I can see the round dot(the picture shows the selected, if set to blue for example, there will be a big blue dot covers the inside small dot and round edge). It is like this

[image]

Any idea why this can happen?

I did some test and found that basically RadioButton doesn't work. I tried it like this

```
<RadioButton GroupName="A" Content="XX" Margin="20,10,10,10"/>
```

but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Why did you bind `IsChecked`?

Comment: @FirstStep, thanks! Because I need to use the status in my viewmodel.

Comment: Is the template of the RadioButton custom at all? What's the point of the embedded TextBlock as opposed to just setting as Content="XX"? Would need more info to diagnose.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried to use content, but it doesn't work. I updated my post a little bit.

Comment: Is the style template for the RadioButton custom at all?

Comment: @ChrisW. You are right, somewhere else, there is a bad style without using key which affected this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's because somewhere else, there is a bad style without using key which affected this radiobutton.